# Applying function to a merged dataset and getiing error

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I had two data sets, one in `data1` and other is `data2`. I merged two data sets by using

```
data = pandas.concat([data1, data2])
```

`data1` and `data2` are same and it is like:

```
     Loan_ID Gender Married Dependents     Education Self_Employed  \
0  LP001002   Male      No          0      Graduate            No   
1  LP001003   Male     Yes          1      Graduate            No  
2  LP001005   Male     Yes          0      Graduate           Yes   
3  LP001006   Male     Yes          0  Not Graduate            No   

   ApplicantIncome  CoapplicantIncome  LoanAmount  Loan_Amount_Term  \
0             5849                0.0         NaN             360.0   
1             4583             1508.0       128.0             360.0   
2             3000                0.0        66.0             360.0   
3             2583             2358.0       120.0             360.0   

   Credit_History Property_Area Loan_Status  
0             1.0         Urban           Y  
1             1.0         Rural           N  
2             1.0         Urban           Y  
3             1.0         Urban           Y  `
```

I created one method:

```
def treat_outlier(x):
    a,b = data[x].quantile([.25,.75])
    IQR = b-a
    for i in range(len(data[x])):
        if(data[x][i]<a-(1.5*IQR) or (data[x][i]>b+(1.5*IQR))):
            data[x][i] = data[x].median()
```

when I individually applied this method to `data1` and `data2`, this function was working, but when I applied it to the merged data set `data`, I got the error:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Why is that so?

Comment: Would you add examples of your `data1` and `data2` dataframes?

Comment: Actually, I got the error. While merging the two datasets, I forgot to add `ignore_index = True`, due to which this error occurred.